# Can I get a single properties values from a List<object>?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class ObjectClass
{
    public string PropA { get; set; }
    public string PropB { get; set; }
}     

 List<string> properties = new List<string>();
 List<ObjectClass> ListObject= new List<ObjectClass>();

 //Fill ListObject
 //...

 foreach (var obj in ListObject)
 {
   properties.Add(obj.PropA);
 }
```

I have a list(string) that I want to populate with all the values of a certain type of parameters from a List(Object). I tried using .FindAll and .Where but those bring back the collection of objects where I want just a single value to be extracted.

Am I restricted to using a For loop in order to pull that out or does Linq have a built in method that might extract it in "one line"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the purpose of the `Select` extension method:

```
properties.AddRange(ListObject.Select(o => o.PropA));
```

The `Select` will project the selected property of each object into a new enumerable.

Comment: Beat me to it by 39 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple select like so:

`properties.AddRange(ObjectList.Select(obj => obj.PropA));`